# How to adjust the position of dropdown menu according to the size of the box (CSS3 family tree)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, tree

I have css3 family tree that when you click on the box a drop-down menu appears.

**Question 1**

I'm trying to make it always appear on the right with `transform: translate3d(90px, 0px, 0px) !important;` but the value `90` would have to vary according to the size of the box.

How can I do that ?

**Question 2**

If the user clicks on department 4, the menu creates an overflow x.

How can I show the menu without overflow ?

[Example of code](https://codepen.io/cplaiuu/pen/gOpmGQJ)

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D I get it, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can reset `left` and then use `right` and `transform: translate3d()` again:

```
.tree div.dropdown-menu {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: unset !important;
    right: -60px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Not sure if I got it right, but for the second question, add `overflow: unset` to the `.tree ul`.

```
.tree ul {
  overflow-x: unset !important;
}
```

I usually do not indicate use of `!Important`, but in this case it is necessary to override the properties.